# Multi-master replication with both snapshot and synchronization replication

Tags: postgresql-12, enterprisedb

We are setting up a Multi-Master replication setup using EDB Rep Server on Postgres. We are unable to create a Publication because some of the tables created by the Keycloak Application does not have Primary keys defined in them and Replication Server mandates tables to have primary keys. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Not so easy to add primary keys to tables created by the third party Keycloak application, not sure of the consequences.

In the same multi-master setup, can we have both synchronization replication and snapshot replication defined but for different set of tables? I assume a snapshot replication wouldn't require this primary key to be defined for the tables.

Comment: Do let me know if that helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. At the moment for MMR you cant create multiple publications.
2. On the other hand in case of SMR you are allowed to create multiple
   publication e.g publication1 with tables having primary keys (that will have
   sync and snapshot support) and another publication2 with tables without
   primary keys (that will only have snapshot support)
3. The other solution is to create MMR publication1 with table having primary key in Database1 and Create a publication in SMR publication2 for tables having no primary keys in Database2. (Note: cant add same database in SMR and MMR simultaneously)

Comment: Thanks, I understand multiple publications cannot be created in MMR. That's a bummer. We have 3 DBs in the same Server and wanted to replicate, looks like xDB doesn't support. Appreciate your feedback. So we may have to move towards BDR now!